# node js mssql issue - adapting a mysql example

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, windows, node-modules

I'm trying to adapt this **mysql** crud example to **mssql**.

http://teknosains.com/i/simple-crud-nodejs-mysql

here the git of that:

https://github.com/codetrash/nodecrud

**I changed this function:**

```
exports.list = function(req, res){

req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer',function(err,rows)
    {

        if(err)
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

        res.render('customers',{page_title:"Customers - Node.js",data:rows});


     });

     //console.log(query.sql);
});

};
```

**To this:**

```
exports.list = function(req, res){

// req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query('SELECT * FROM customer',function(err,rows)
    {
        console.log(rows);
        if(err)
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

        res.render('customers',{page_title:"customer - Node.js",data:rows});


     });

     //console.log(query.sql);
});
//sql.close();

};
```

I get the output of the query on the console, so the connection to the database and the query itself is fine,  but it doesn't get implemented into the ejs file.
(link to ejs: https://github.com/codetrash/nodecrud/blob/master/views/customers.ejs)

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mssql`, the `query`'s callback does not return the rows directly, it returns an object. *Inside* that return object is the array `recordset`, which contains your rows.

Here is an example from the [`mssql` documentation page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#query-command-callback)

```
request.query('select 1 as number; select 2 as number', (err, result) => {
    // ... error checks

    console.log(result.recordset[0].number) // return 1
    console.log(result.recordsets[0][0].number) // return 1
    console.log(result.recordsets[1][0].number) // return 2
})
```

(By the way, `(err, result) => { }` is the same as `function(err, result) { }` in this instance)

**NB!** The difference between recordset and recordset**s**: In case your `query` calls for multiple `select`s, they will be accessible via `recordset[x]`. However as far as I know, `recordset` is always the result of the first `select` in your `query`; you can just use `recordset` for cleaner-looking code.

Just change your code to something like

```
request.query('SELECT * FROM customer',function(err,result)
{
    console.log(result);
    if(err)
        console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

    res.render('customers',{page_title:"customer - Node.js",data:result.recordset});


 });
```